# Can I make a Win32 child window show under the parent window?

Tags: windows, winapi, window

I want to add a child window to a parent window,make the content of child window is below the parent window(Z order).just like compose two layer,not replacement.Because I want some UI element in parent window can be seen within the child window's area,but not cover all of the child window.The child window should be a window,so I can't just using parent window's UI system to implement the child window's UI.

Is there any api to achieve this?

I found something like "UpdateLayeredWindow",But I failed to create a layer child window,CreateWindowEx return NULL and GetLastError return 0.This code was copy from [Windows's example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples).and the demo project (DirectCompositionLayeredChildWindow) works well.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

// Register the window class.
WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
wc.lpszClassName = L"DirectComposition Window Class";

RegisterClassEx(&wc);

// Creates the m_hMainWindow window.
HWND m_hMainWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW| WS_EX_COMPOSITED,                          // Extended window style
    wc.lpszClassName,                                // Name of window class
    L"DirectComposition Layered Child Window Sample", // Title-bar string
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU,                      // Top-level window
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                                   // Horizontal position
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                                   // Vertical position
    1000,                                            // Width
    700,                                             // Height
    NULL,                                            // Parent
    NULL,                                            // Class menu
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),                           // Handle to application instance
    NULL                                             // Window-creation data
);

if (!m_hMainWindow)
{
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    ShowWindow(m_hMainWindow, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}


WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.lpszClassName = L"DirectCompositionChildWindow-Child";

RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

// !!! m_hControlChildWindow is always NULL
HWND m_hControlChildWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,                           // Extended window style
    wcex.lpszClassName,                      // Name of window class
    NULL,                                    // Title-bar string
    WS_CHILD,              // Child window
    30,30, 100, 100,                              // Window will be resized via MoveWindow
    m_hMainWindow,                           // Parent
    NULL,                                    // Class menu
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),                   // Handle to application instance
    NULL);                                   // Window-creation data

if (!m_hControlChildWindow)
{
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}
ShowWindow(m_hControlChildWindow, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(m_hControlChildWindow);
```

Comment: "Under" is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean that the parent overlaps the child window and obscures it? (Z order)? Or is it below the parent window in the Y direction?

Comment: So this is z order in windows terms. I don't think Y direction is helpful here. Y is the horizontal axis. But a child window is not a top level window. So do you mean something other than a child window? Unless we all use the same terminology it's very hard to have these conversations. Read MSDN to find the official terminology.

Comment: For example,parent window is full screen's size,child window is 480*320 within the parent window. First, child window can be see; Second,I want to drag a item from parent window's other area to child window,and the item can be see when it's draged to child window's area.

Comment: A parent window can normally draw inside its children (unless you set the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style on the parent).

Comment: @JonathanPotter I tried this,set parent window transparent,without WS_CLIPCHILDREN style,and add child window to it, but the child window can't be seen(it can be seen when it's not added to the parent).

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#positioning):

> No part of a child window ever appears outside the borders of its parent window.

[Also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#z-order):

> A child window is grouped with its parent in z-order.

In other words: You cannot create a child window that's either outside the parent window's client area, or underneath the parent window in Z-order.

Comment: The child window won't be outside the borders.I update my comment,sorry for my poor English ability.